# Pass dynamic image parameter to modal-dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, advanced-custom-fields

I am implemeting a system where the user clicks on an image and is redirected to another website. Before redirecting a modal dialog appears and confirms that they will be redirected to another website.

The images are added dynamically from the back-end by the client and the client adds a unique service link to each image resulting in:

```
    <!-- image #1 -->
        <a href="#openModal"> <!-- opens the modal dialog -->
          <div class="service">   
                <img src="img.png"> <!-- unique image -->
          </div>
        </a>
    <!-- image #2 etc -->
        <a href="#openModal"> <!-- opens the modal dialog -->
          <div class="service">   
                <img src="img2.png"> <!-- unique image -->
          </div>
        </a>

<!-- clicking on image #1 -->

    <div id="openModal">
    <p>You will be now redirected to the service provider home page</p>
    <a href="http://unique_link_to_img#1_service" target="_blank">Order</a><!-- link entered in the back end of service that is unique with each service provider image -->
    </div>
```

How could I achieve this without knowing a certain ID to each image?

Thanks O.

Comment: which modal dialog widget you are using?

Comment: No widget, I'm using this css only modal, shown here in my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pw8w1x6d/3/ . This fiddle is used in another section on my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please take a look at below fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/pw8w1x6d/4/

**HTML Code:**

```
<a href="#openModal" class="openlink"> <!-- opens the modal dialog -->
          <div class="service">   
                <img src="img.png"> <!-- unique image -->
          </div>
        Open Modal</a>
    <!-- image #2 etc -->
        <a href="#openModal" class="openlink"> <!-- opens the modal dialog -->
          <div class="service">   
                <img src="img2.png"> <!-- unique image -->
          </div>
        Open Modal</a>


<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <div class="selectedImage"></div>
<a href="javascript:if(document.getElementById('listUpdate').value) window.open(document.getElementById('listUpdate').value);" target="_blank">Submit</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".openlink", function(){
        var imagePath = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
        $(".selectedImage").text(imagePath);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, got it working: https://jsfiddle.net/pw8w1x6d/7/ as planned thanks to your fiddle update